# Apache ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch to exclude a file from proxying

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, proxypass, exclude

I have a VirtualHost set to proxy all requests to another server running on port 9000.

What I have :

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
```

What I've tried :

```
! ProxyPass /test.html http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPass /test.html ! http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassMatch !^/(.*\.html)$ http://localhost:9000/$1
```

None of which worked...

I'd like to exclude a file or a set of files from being proxied, the documentation says something about "The ! directive is useful in situations where you don't want to reverse-proxy a subdirectory.", but there are no examples for that situation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, figured it out, turns out that - obviously - there's no need to specify the proxy for excluded paths.

> ProxyPass /somedir !

works great

Comment: Hmm.  This is interesting because if you were using AJP to link to Tomcat (for serving dynamic JSP content) , then this directive might allow you to , for example, exclude the "/images" directory on the server so that Tomcat serves the images instead of Tomcat???

Comment: Well, it does. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Note that this has to go before the other ProxyPass directives in order to have an effect, since the first match is the one that gets applied.